# How to install mod_wsgi 3.1 on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, python, ubuntu-9.10, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a Python 3 web app so mod_wsgi < 3.1 doesn't cut it for me. However, on my Ubuntu 9.10 installation there doesn't seem to be a package for mod_wsgi 3.1.

1. Is there an alternative repository that has a package for mod_wsgi 3.1?
2. There's a new Ubuntu release not so long from now, will it contain mod_wsgi 3.1?
3. Some other distro ready with mod_wsgi 3.1 to recommend?
4. Maybe my best bet is to compile it myself? From a quick google it looks like I only need the python and apache dev packages installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For question 2, it looks like [Lucid (10.04) will have 2.8](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libapache2-mod-wsgi). Probably compiling it yourself should not be too difficult.

Comment: Which is sad in itself given that even Ubuntu and Redhat Fedora have mod_wsgi 3.2 in their repositories now. Ubuntu just isn't keeping up these days if they only have mod_wsgi 2.8. :-(

Comment: Graham, ubuntu has packages for 3.2 and 3.3, but note that his asking about ubuntu version 9.10 means he is asking about ubuntu released in October, 2009

Comment: The answer was saying that 10.04 at the time would still only have 2.8.